# Are there any efficient micro-optimizations to find the number of unique grid paths?

Tags: java, micro-optimization

I am trying to solve this CSES problem: [Grid Paths](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1625/). You are given a string of length 48, and you have to find the amount of paths such that you traverse all of the grid and end up at the lower left corner.

I believe I have pruned the search to the best of my ability, as according to this book: [CP Handbook](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf) (Look in the pruning the search category), the best optimization for this type of problem is to prevent your path from closing yourself off, and I have already implemented this. The time limits for this specific problem are tight, and although I have basically solved this problem, I am still failing 1-2 test cases because my solution takes around 1.01 seconds instead of being below the 1 second time limit.

Finally, I just wanted to know if there were any cool micro-optimizations I could use to marginally enhance the speed of my java code, so I could actually pass all of the test cases for this problem.

```
import java.io.*;

public class GridPaths {
    public static class FastIO {
        InputStream dis;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1 << 17];
        int pointer = 0;

        public FastIO(String fileName) throws Exception {
            dis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        }

        public FastIO(InputStream is) {
            dis = is;
        }

        int nextInt() throws Exception {
            int ret = 0;
            byte b;
            do {
                b = nextByte();
            } while (b <= ' ');
            boolean negative = false;
            if (b == '-') {
                negative = true;
                b = nextByte();
            }
            while (b >= '0' && b <= '9') {
                ret = 10 * ret + b - '0';
                b = nextByte();
            }
            return (negative) ? -ret : ret;
        }

        long nextLong() throws Exception {
            long ret = 0;
            byte b;
            do {
                b = nextByte();
            } while (b <= ' ');
            boolean negative = false;
            if (b == '-') {
                negative = true;
                b = nextByte();
            }
            while (b >= '0' && b <= '9') {
                ret = 10 * ret + b - '0';
                b = nextByte();
            }
            return (negative) ? -ret : ret;
        }

        Integer[] readArray(int n) throws Exception {
            Integer[] a = new Integer[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = nextInt();
            return a;
        }

        byte nextByte() throws Exception {
            if (pointer == buffer.length) {
                dis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                pointer = 0;
            }
            return buffer[pointer++];
        }

        String next() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
            byte b;
            do {
                b = nextByte();
            } while (b <= ' ');
            while (b > ' ') {
                ret.appendCodePoint(b);
                b = nextByte();
            }
            return ret.toString();
        }
    }

    static char[] board;
    static boolean[][] visited = new boolean[7][7];
    static int ans = 0;

    public static boolean works(int i, int j) {
        //makes sure that current spot is on the 7x7 grid and is not visited
        return (i >= 0 && i<=6 && j>=0 && j<=6 && !visited[i][j]);
    }
    public static void solve(int i, int j, int steps) {
        if (i == 6 && j == 0) {
            if (steps == 48) ans++; //all spots of the grid have to be visited in order to be counted as part of the answer
            return;
        }
        visited[i][j] = true;
        //you are given ? characters in the input string, and those mean that you have to try out all 4 combinations (U,D,L,R)
        if (board[steps] == '?' || board[steps] == 'L') {
            //second condition of the second if statement checks if the spot directly ahead of the current spot is blocked, and if it is, the left and right spots cannot both be unvisited or else you will not continue searching 
            if (works(i,j-1) && !(!works(i,j-2) && works(i+1,j-1) && works(i-1,j-1))) {
                solve(i, j - 1, steps + 1);
            }
        }
        if (board[steps] == '?' || board[steps] == 'R') {
            if (works(i,j+1) && !(!works(i,j+2) && works(i+1,j+1) && works(i-1,j+1))) {
                solve(i, j + 1, steps + 1);
            }
        }
        if (board[steps] == '?' || board[steps] == 'U') {
            if (works(i-1,j) && !(!works(i-2,j) && works(i-1,j+1) && works(i-1,j-1))) {
                solve(i - 1, j, steps + 1);
            }
        }
        if (board[steps] == '?' || board[steps] == 'D') {
            if (works(i+1,j) && !(!works(i+2,j) && works(i+1,j+1) && works(i+1,j-1))) {
                solve(i + 1, j, steps + 1);
            }
        }
        visited[i][j] = false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FastIO in = new FastIO(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        board = in.next().toCharArray();
        solve(0,0,0);
        out.println(ans);

        out.close();
    }

}
```

Note: I am already using one of the fastest, if not the fastest, ways to receive input in Java, so I do not believe I can actually improve upon that.

Comment: String `next()` could maybe benefit from looking at the IO buffer directly and calling a Java builtin function to scan for the next char >= `' '`, if there is one.  I expect that will JIT compile into a byte-at-a-time loop, but could go 16x as fast with SIMD if there are long runs of whitespace / control characters. Similarly for finding the range of non-whitespace bytes and copying it into a String; that could avoid StringBuilder, and (in the optimistic case where the end is found before the end of the input buffer) avoid saving a partially-constructed String / StringBuilder during an IO call

Comment: Have you profiled to find out where it spends most of its CPU time?  Presumably in the recursive `solve()`, so micro-optimizing the IO would probably be negligible.

Comment: What is the format of the data you're reading?  Is it just the string of 48 characters in a file?  If so, why is 60% of your code just for reading a String from a file that can only contain combinations of ASCII characters?  I compared your FastIO class against the FileInputStream class, doing 1000 reps of reading randomly generated strings of 48 characters from a file, and FileInputStream was better than 3x faster than your class.  So if that's part of what's being timed, maybe you can just replace your FastIO class with FileInputStream and you'll be done.

Comment: @Steve The IO was just part of a template. According to multiple sources, this is the one of the fastest ways to get IO available currently for Java. But for some reason, I just switched it to BufferedReader and I was able to submit everything within the time limit. This doesn't make a lot of sense as on questions such as https://www.spoj.com/problems/INTEST/ , they have a large amount of input (around  10^7 different integers), and this FastIO was able to complete it in around .3 seconds while just using BufferedReader was about .65 seconds.

Comment: @Krish: I'm not surprised those I/O functions are good for *large* input streams, where it doesn't all fit in one buffer (especially for integers but maybe not so much for string words). But you have a different case, where the input is small and does fit in a single input buffer, right? And would probably fit in whatever internal buffer standard Java IO classes use.  If most of your CPU time is *not* I/O, IDK why this would make a big difference, but it should be obvious that a piece of code can be fast or slow for different use-cases. Did the fast test-case you looked at mostly read numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around with this.  In addition to using a standard mechanism for reading the input file (which I suggested in a comment), you can gain a little time in the search alg itself by doing two things:

1. Break the case `board[steps] == '?'` off from the other cases.  So check for `board[steps] == '?'` first, and just try all four directions in that case.  Otherwise (the `else` case for `if (board[steps] == '?')`, just check for U/D/L/R.  Since for most steps, the character will be '?', you save having to make the U/D/L/R tests most of the time.
2. Look up the character to be tested once, with `c = board[steps]`,and then use `c` in each test instead of `board[steps]`.

Doing these two things saved about 5% it seems.  I was doing 100 reps of the solve and timing with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  I know there are more accurate ways of timing, but this was good enough to see a definite improvement even though the times jumped around quite a bit trial to trial.  The best I ever saw in each case was 3600 millis for 100 iterations as originally written vs 3400 millis with the improvements.

My guess is that it's mostly the first change that matters.  I'd expect the compiler to be doing the second already, but I didn't try the two optimizations independently.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this problem in java (AC), and here is how I did it

```
public static char[] defaultPath;
public static boolean[][] isUsed;
public static int counter = 0;

public static void solve(int indexChar, int indexRow, int indexColumn) {
    if (indexRow == 8 && indexColumn == 2) {
        if (indexChar == 48) {
            counter++;
        }
    }else {
        // Find correct way: 'D', 'U', 'L', 'R'
        char correctWay = '?';
        // (1)          (1)
        //  0 1   or   1 0
        //  1            1
        if ((isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn+1] || isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn-1])
                && isUsed[indexRow+2][indexColumn] && !isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn]) {
            correctWay = 'D';
        }
        //  1            1 
        //  0 1   or   1 0
        // (1)          (1)
        else if ((isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn+1] || isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn-1])
                && !isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] && isUsed[indexRow-2][indexColumn]) {
            correctWay = 'U';
        }
        // 1 0 (1)   or    1
        //   1           1 0 (1)
        else if ((isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn-1] || isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn-1])
                && !isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] && isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-2]) {
            correctWay = 'L';
        }
        //(1) 0 1    or      1
        //    1          (1) 0 1
        else if ((isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn+1] || isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn+1])
                && !isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] && isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+2]) {
            correctWay = 'R';
        }
        
        // Check input path (default path)
        char c = defaultPath[indexChar];
        if (c == '?') {
            if (correctWay == '?') {
                // 'D'
                if (!isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow+1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = false;
                }
                // 'U'
                if (!isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow-1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = false;
                }
                // 'L'
                if (!isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn-1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = false;
                }
                // 'R'
                if (!isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn+1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = false;
                }
            }else {
                if (correctWay == 'D') {
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow+1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = false;
                }else if (correctWay == 'U') {
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow-1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = false;
                }else if (correctWay == 'L') {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn-1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = false;
                }else if (correctWay == 'R') {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn+1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = false;
                }
            }
        }else {
            if (c == correctWay || correctWay == '?') {
                if (c == 'D' && !isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow+1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow+1][indexColumn] = false;
                }else if (c == 'U' && !isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow-1, indexColumn);
                    isUsed[indexRow-1][indexColumn] = false;
                }else if (c == 'L' && !isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn-1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn-1] = false;
                }else if (c == 'R' && !isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1]) {
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = true;
                    solve(indexChar+1, indexRow, indexColumn+1);
                    isUsed[indexRow][indexColumn+1] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    defaultPath = scanner.next().toCharArray();
    isUsed = new boolean[11][11];
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        isUsed[0][i] = true;
        isUsed[1][i] = true;
        isUsed[9][i] = true;
        isUsed[10][i] = true;
        isUsed[i][0] = true;
        isUsed[i][1] = true;
        isUsed[i][9] = true;
        isUsed[i][10] = true;
    }
    isUsed[2][2] = true;
    isUsed[8][1] = false;
    isUsed[9][2] = false;
    solve(0, 2, 2);

    System.out.println(counter);
    scanner.close();
}
```